# ggplot2 (version 3) incompatibility with ggmap for geom_density_2d

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

`ggplot2` version 3 seems to have an incompatibility with `ggmap` when using the `geom_density2d()` function to add a layer. The following code returns an error (though worked with `ggplot2` version 2):

```
# Create a data frame
df <- data.frame(
  long = rnorm(50, -122.32, .2), 
  lat = rnorm(50, 47.6, .2) 
)

# Use qmplot to create a base layer of map tiles
base_plot <- qmplot(
  data = df, 
  x = long, # data feature for longitude
  y = lat, # data feature for latitude
  geom = "blank", # don't display data points (yet)
  maptype = "toner-background", # map tiles to query
  darken = .7, # darken the map tiles
  legend = "topleft" # location of legend on page
)

# Show the map in RStudio
base_plot

# Use ggplot to create a 2d density map (without tiles -- works fine)
ggplot(df, aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
  geom_density2d() + 
  stat_density_2d(
    aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = stat(level)), # in v2, fill = ..level..
    # Use the computed density to set the fill
    alpha = .3,
    geom="polygon" # Set the alpha (transparency)
  )

# Add 2d density plot on map tiles -- returns an error
base_plot + 
  geom_density2d() + 
  stat_density_2d(
    aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = stat(level)), # in v2, fill = ..level..
    # Use the computed density to set the fill
    alpha = .3,
    geom="polygon" # Set the alpha (transparency)
  )

# Error in width_cm(guide$barwidth %||% theme$legend.key.width) : 
 # Unknown input
```

Any guidance on how to use `geom_density2d()` to add a layer to a `qmplot()` map would be appreciated!

(Map below of the image created with `ggplot2` version 2)
[image: Map created with geom_density]

Comment: Seems like you specifically have an issue with `ggmap`. You'll probably get better help by reporting an issue at https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues. ggplot 3.0 was just recently released. The author may have not had time to update the package yet.

Comment: Works fine for me. You should use the dev ggmap version `devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")`

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments via @Tung: the issue is with `ggmap`, and the solution is to use the development version of ggmap (`devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")`